# Magento mobile Theme "add to cart" issue

Tags: magento-1.9, theme, css, html, mobile

I am using a Magento version 1.9.0.1. I have installed a mobile theme, which is working fine except "add to cart" function. Nothing happens when I press it, I have tried it on my Samsung Galaxy S3.

I tried also the solution here but it does not work

http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/m/viewthread/290453/#t474173

Comment: Does it work from a non-mobile device?

Comment: Please provide a link to the site, there's no way we can pinpoint the issue from the description provided. Also have you tried contacting the theme developer for support?

Comment: Have you tried to turn on debug logging to see if there are any errors?